# Como "fuso horário" ou só "fuso" virou o mesmo que "qual a diferença do horário"

Tags: português-brasileiro, significado-em-contexto

Em outros idiomas, como o inglês, perguntar sobre o "timezone" de um local significa querer saber a Zona Horária (ex: Horário Padrão de Brasília). Porém, atualmente, observei que muitas pessoas perguntam sobre o fuso horário de um local querendo saber apenas a diferença de horário entre aquele local e o Brasil.

Então, como é que a pergunta "qual o fuso horário de Roma" passou a significar não "em que fuso horário está Roma" (+2:00) mas "qual a diferença horária daqui (GMT-3) para Roma (GMT+2)" (+5h)?

Comment: Não percebo bem a pergunta. Podes explicitar a diferença entre as duas coisas? Qual é, para ti, a diferença entre Zona Horária e fuso horário?

Comment: Zona Horária e fuso horário são sinônimos. A pergunta é como "Qual o fuso horário de Atenas?" virou sinônimo de "Qual a diferença entre o [meu] horário local e Atenas?". A princípio a resposta seria "Horário de verão da europa oriental" ou GMT+3. Porém a reposta mais satisfatória ao público geral me parece ser "Atenas está 6 horas a frente do horário de Brasília".

Comment: Ah, já percebi. Vou fazer uma edição a tentar melhorar a pergunta, vê se concordas.

Comment: Eu acho que a questão continua a significar o mesmo, simplesmente as pessoas respondem indiretamente ao dizer a diferença em vez de dizer o fuso horário.

Answer (score 1):

Muitas vezes respondemos a uma pergunta não literalmente, mas dando como resposta a informação que acreditamos que realmente se deseja. Por exemplo,

> — Você tem cerveja?
>   — Está lá no armário da esquerda.

Ou ainda,

> — Você se incomoda se eu abrir a janela?
>   — Pode abrir sim.

Outras vezes damos a resposta que mais facilmente podemos dar, mesmo que não corresponda exatamente à pergunta feita. Por exemplo,

> — Que horas são?
>   — Não devem ser nem 5:30h ainda.

E ainda outras vezes, por hábito ou costume, a informação pode ser dada numa forma indireta ou não usual. Por exemplo:

> — Qual é a área do terreno?
>   — Dá um campo de futebol.

Em algumas situações, as três possibilidades acima se aplicam, como na sua pergunta:

> — Qual o fuso horário de Roma?
>   — Está 5h à frente do de Brasília.

e também em:

> — Qual é a distância até Curitiba?
>   — Dá quase 8h.

Em que o tempo de viagem pode ser a informação que realmente se deseja, ou é única que o respondente tinha à disposição, ou é a maneira habitual de se medir distâncias (se a velocidade média é conhecida implicitamente).

Comment: De acordo. E seria possível levar o argumento mais longe; ou talvez seja trazê-lo mais perto. Por exemplo, supõe que estás no Recife (GMT-3) e te perguntam qual o fuso horário de Lisboa (agora, GMT+1). É igualmente correto dizer que Lisboa são mais quatro horas (que no Recife) ou que Lisboa é GMT + uma hora. No primeiro caso dás a hora relativamente ao Recife; no segundo caso é relativamente ao GMT. É sempre relativo a alguma coisa.

Comment: @Jacinto Sim, essa grandeza especificamente costuma ser quantificada de maneira relativa, mas não precisa: também se podem usar os nomes absolutos, como CET (Central European Time) e CEST (horário de verão na CET).

Comment: (@stafusa Lisboa está em GMT com daylight saving, não está em CET - que é GMT+1.)

Comment: @ANeves Você tem razão, mas eu ainda pensava em Roma (do OP), que está em CEST no momento.

Comment: Mas mesmo que digas que Madrid ou Argel é CET, não continua a ser relativo: é a mesma hora que o CET. Eu parece-me que qualquer sistema de localização é intrinsecamente relativo a um referencial qualquer; a posição (no tempo ou espaço) é sempre relativa a outra coisa; coincidir com o referencial é ainda uma relação. Para a maior parte das pessoas o referencial menos arbitrário é capaz de ser mesmo a hora do sítio onde está.

Comment: @Jacinto Não, penso que sua colocação não é precisa: nem todo sistema de localização é relativo, especialmente quando ao invés de coordenas ele se utiliza de nomenclatura. Por exemplo, França é França num sentido absoluto, não relativo a alguma outra localização; ou ainda, ao se referir a Portugal, não se está fazendo nenhuma referência implícita ao fato dele estar na Península Ibérica. Da mesma forma, CET não é lugar, é um tempo padrão, e pode-seode-se descrevê-lo como UTC+01:00, mas não são sinônimos.

Comment: Sou capaz de já estar para aqui a rachar cabelos, mas se disseres que Paris fica em França, a tua localização de Paris é relativa (a França). Precisamente por eu não interpretar CET como lugal, é que eu o vejo como relativo. Os vários fusos (padrões) horários são definidos relativamente uns aos outros, por isso é que diferem entre si em múltiplos inteiros de uma hora (não sei se não haverá também meias horas), mesmo que possam ser designados por "CET" e similares que não façam referência a outros fusos. Logo, dizer que Roma agora é CEST, UTC+2 ou hora de Recife + 5 dá a mesma informação.

Comment: Só para clarificar, eu reitero o "De acordo" (meu primeiro comentário) acerca da tua resposta, e o upvote é meu (ahhg, não costumo divulgar esta informação :) )

Comment: @Jacinto Hehehe... tudo bem, eu já tinha entendido assim, mas obrigado por esclarecer. Acho que não estou conseguindo me explicar muito - e não devo conseguir muito melhor - ou a gente discorda mesmo. De qualquer forma, penso que podemos encerrar a discussão.